# Does kevent discard the changelist when interrupted by a signal?

Tags: c, signals, kevent

When `kevent` returns `EINTR`, which is a likely occurrence because it does not support `SA_RESTART` behavior, has the changelist been applied or not?

I get the impression it has, because signals generate `EINTR` only after the thread has gone to sleep, which only happens after the changelist is applied. Right?